# Receiving an error Unable to deploy the data stream, please try again. GackId: 1696355462-9454 (1293454336) when trying to deploy a data stream

Tags: salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

When I try to deploy an AWS data stream, I receive an error

Unable to deploy the data stream, please try again. GackId: 1696355462-9454 (1293454336)

Why does it happen and how can I overcome it?

[image]

Comment: I'd file a bug report with salesforce.com. It seems like something they could easily fix.

Comment: well, I recently filed a lot of bug reports using Salesforce support cases; I am just tired of that :)

Comment: unfortunately there is no form to directly report the bug, but you must open a case and explain and argue that this is a really a bug even if it is happening in a trial org expiring soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error happens since `File Name` attribute is blank.

It is kind of misleading since this attribute is optional and not required on the user interface and users may assume it is indeed optional while in fact it is required.